# Detect Maven build status (SUCCESS/ERROR) from a Maven plugin

Tags: maven-2, build-process, maven-plugin, mojo

I am wondering how would one get the status of a build (`ERROR`/`SUCCESS`) from a Maven plugin ?

Comment: May I ask you: what is your use case?

Answer (score 4):

You can't easily do that. Maven plugins fail by throwing a `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException`
 or a `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException`, and you don't have a hook to listen to these exceptions. Certainly not with a plugin, because your plugin wouldn't be executed after a failure.

There might be the possibility to use custom versions of

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor`
or 
`org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven`

that you can inject via plexus and wrap plugin execution in try / catch to perfom your logic afterwards, but this is very heavy stuff.

Read here about [accessing the plexus container](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-intro-plexus.html)